# How do I handle using 1 model to belong_to 2 different models at different times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am creating a Shopping Cart.

So I will have a model called `LineItem`.

Each instance of a cart will have 1+ line items. As will a completed transaction - which becomes an 'order'.

So, in theory, a LineItem `belongs_to` Cart and also `belongs_to` Order.

But, what would the DB table look like? a `cart_id` and `order_id` in my `LineItems` table?

That would mean that for every valid cart record, there will be an `order_id` that is nil (or empty). Likewise, for every valid order, there will be an empty `cart_id`.

This seems like a non-Railsy way to do this.

What is the best way to do this? A polymorphic association? What would that look like if I should do that?

Comment: You should think if LineItem - Cart/Order is really one-to-many relationship. I think it's many-to-many so first you should consider has_many through or has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

Comment: It is 1 to many. 1 cart has many LineItems. 1 LineItem can't belong to many carts. However, 1 LineItem can belong to a cart + an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line item model can have two belongs_to associations

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cart
    belongs_to :order
end
```

But this can get messy if it needs to belong to several different classes. The solution is polymorphic association which allows a model to belong to more than one model on a SINGLE association, which in the example below is `:line_itemable`. It will add two attributes, `line_itemable_id` and `line_itemable_type` to the LineItem model.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :line_itemable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, :as => :line_itemable
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, :as => :line_itemable
end
```

If cart and order share similar attributes such as cost, then another option is to eliminate the order class and simply add a `:paid` flag on the cart.

Comment: So I would just do a `rails g model LineItem`, and not `rails g model LineItemable`?

Comment: Also...what migrations should I run?

Comment: LineItem is the name of the model, line_itemable is the name of the association. So ```rails g model LineItem line_itemable_id:integer line_itemable_type:string```

Comment: By the way....in my `Cart` or `Order` model, what foreign key would I add? Just `line_item_id`? Or nothing?

Comment: the declaration ```has_many :line_items, :as => :line_itemable``` should suffice

Comment: Yeh...I saw that in the guides. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest polymorphic association.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end



class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :owner
end



class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :owner
end
```

you will need to add owner_type and owner_id to line_items table.

Refer [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: This is a good start, but it is a bit confusing. I prefer @omarshammas answer.